# XML document opens with the function echo

Tags: php, xml, echo

I come again to ask you help, I wanted to know what is the mistake I am making. I liked that with the echo function to be able to have access to  Artist, Song and JazlerID. I leave here the xml document link that holds the information http://inlivefm.6te.net/AirPlayNext.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Event status="coming up">
  <Song title="IN THE MORNING LIGHT">
   <Artist name="ALEX SCHULZ" > 
   </Artist>
    <Info StartTime="21:55:08" JazlerID="7"  />
  </Song>

 </Event>
```

this is the code I'm using to find out JazlerID

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://inlivefm.6te.net/AirPlayNext.xml");
print $xml>Event->Jazler['ID'];
?>
```

Other place thanks for availability and am awaiting some respost

Comment: Typo here?: "print $xml>Event->Jazler['ID']" . It should be "print $xml->Event->Jazler['ID']" (look at "->")

Comment: Giuseppe I tried to change to the SETTINGS and I could not get the information appears blank page

Comment: There's no XML element `<Jazler>` in that URL's content. Also the error pointed out above.

Answer (score 2):

The `SimpleXMLElement` returned by `simplexml_load_file()` is the root element (so `<Event>` in this case). You also access attributes (such as `JazlerID`) like array elements so what you want is

```
echo $xml->Song->Info['JazlerID'];
```

Comment: Many thanks to everyone who helped me solve it, I used the code Phil and resulted in what I wanted, thank you!